# Is it possible to label the tick marks on an NSSlider

Tags: cocoa, nsslider

I have some vertical sliders and I want to be able to label the tick marks with the values they represent.  Is there a better way to do this besides manually putting labels next to them in the Interface Builder?  If not, is there a way to at least make those labels line up right with the tick marks or do I have to do it freehand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any builtin capability to label tickmarks. However, see `NSSliderCell`, which has a method called `-rectOfTickMarkAtIndex:`: [Apple's NSSliderCell documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSliderCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSliderCell/rectOfTickMarkAtIndex%3a)

This appears to be the way to ensure your labels are correctly aligned with the tick marks.